# C++ Dynamic Allocation with vectors and containers

Tags: c++, pointers, vector, dynamic, allocation

1.What is the use of dynamic allocating vectors on the heap and is it a good practice?

2.What is the difference between the following:-

```
vector<Object> *col = new vector<Object>
 
vector<Object*> col
```

3.Does vectors dynamically allocate items on the heap in the following example:-

```
vector<Object> x;

or

vector<int> x;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should almost always write `vector<Object>` or `vector<int>` (and maybe `vector<vector<Object>>`.

Your other syntaxes (`vector<Object>*` and `vector<Object*>`) are often inappropriate in C++.  See [`std::unique_ptr`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr) (or [`std::shared_ptr`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr)) for preferred alternatives.